# Android: XmlPullParser getAttributeValue returns null

Tags: android, soap, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest, ksoap2

I am trying a SOAP parsing xml by using **XmlPullParser**.But am always getting null as result.

```
<soap:Body>
<Quote>
<ROLE>Error</ROLE>
<ERRORCODE>3</ERRORCODE>
 <ERRORSTRING>Username and password wrong!!!</ERRORSTRING>
</Quote>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am trying to read each node value XMLPullParser

```
XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
myparser.setInput(inputStream, null);
int event = myparser.getEventType();
while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
{
  String name=myparser.getName();
  switch (event){
   case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
    if(name.equals("ERRORSTRING")){
    Log.e("Tag ","if xml data "+myparser.getAttributeValue(name,"value"));
   }
   break;
   case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
    if(name.equals("Quote")){
     Log.e("Tag ","xml data    "+myparser.getAttributeValue(null,"ERRORSTRING"));
     }
   break;
   }
  event = myparser.next();
 }
```

am getting null value as result.

Can any one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this Way:

```
XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
myparser.setInput(inputStream, null);
int event = myparser.getEventType();
while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
{
  String name=myparser.getName();
  switch (event){
   case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
    if(name.equals("ERRORSTRING")){
    Log.e("Tag ","if xml data "+myparser.getAttributeValue(name,"value"));
   if(name.equals("Quote")){
     Log.e("Tag ","xml data    "+myparser.getAttributeValue(null,"ERRORSTRING"));
     }
   break;

   case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
    break;
   }
  event = myparser.next();
 }
```